# Crystal Reports - How to set database credentials

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I've created some crystal reports. When I run these reports on my system it is working perfectly but when I build the project and installed (exe) on another machine it is asking for database credentials and is not working. Could you please somebody help on this issue?

Comment: review your connection string to the db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to set the credentials to access the database

```
reportDocument.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "password", "server", "database");
```