# why crystal report viewer control toolbar is not working over web browser after report display on web browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am able to display the report on web browser.My problem is, when I use the toolbar(such as export button,print button,find button and so on) of crystal report I am facing the parameter missing error over web browser.Please help me how to shut out this issue in asp.net platform by using c#.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post some code-behind of your page, please

Answer (score 0):

You need to store/persist your reportdocument object in session variables

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   rpt = new ReportDocument();
   Session["report"] = rprt;    // store the report in the Session
}
else
{
  rpt = (ReportDocument)Session["report"];
}
```

and here is the explanation

http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports-for-visual-studio/blog/2011/04/25/why-should-i-store-reports-object-in-httpsession

Comment: Thanks your suggestion, when I added this code in Page_Load event then it works that means missing parameter error is fixed now but one thing crystal report credential is prompt on web browser. Can you please suggest me how to pro grammatically fix the credential.

Comment: If the above answer solved your problem then please mark it as answer and for your new question please post a new question.  for the solutions please look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486925/crystal-reports-how-to-set-database-credentials