# how to automatically pass login credentials to crystal reports

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I keep getting asked for login credentials each time I run a crystal report in my application in visual studio as show in the image below. I managed to deploy the application onto another computer and the same thing happened.
How do i make sure this doesn't happen?

[image: login image]

Comment: It would help if you included what version of `Crystal Reports` you are using and how you are trying to generate these reports. Until then, I can't help I am afraid; this has been asked before here many times as well. It's hard to help with nothing to go on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crystal Reports - How to set database credentials](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486925/crystal-reports-how-to-set-database-credentials)

Comment: i am using crystal reports 13 and visual studio 2010

Comment: theres a lot of resources available on this topic. have you tried googling?